# How to kill a thread in PHPmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a thread showing in PHPmyadmin under processes. However, when I click `kill`, I get the error:

```
phpMyAdmin was unable to kill thread 148. It probably has already been closed.
```

Why does this thread still then show as active? How can I remove it entirely?

Comment: provide output SHOW PROCESSLIST . What is the State, Command, Info of the process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open mysql client and type

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             | Rows_sent | Rows_examined | Rows_read |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| 106 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |         0 |             0 |         0 |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

you'll see processes with ID, than you can do this:

```
mysql> kill 106;
```

and your process (id = 106) will be killed.

Comment: Unfortunately the process ID is not shown, could this be a phpmyadmin bug?

Answer (score 1):

Between the time that phpMyAdmin received the list of processes and the time you clicked to kill one of them, this process had finished by itself.

See also https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1490/.

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon is caused by the connection used to access PHPmyadmin itself, hence it doesn't show on the direct MySQLQuery. It can't be killed, as it would close the PHPmyadmin connection.